# Liferay: Verify if exist screenName on LDAP

Tags: ldap, liferay

I need to call LDAP to see if the user exists. 
The registration of the account will be enabled only for screenName that are present on LDAP.
I have configured LDAP correctly on Liferay but I do not have to enable importing from LDAP.

Which class and method should I use just to check if the screenName exists on LDAP?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can do this replacing default Screen Name Validator, overwriting the next property at portal-ext.properties

```
users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.DefaultScreenNameValidator
```

Put your [package].[class] here. Please, check the following link, can guide you:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/DefaultScreenNameValidator.java

At the end, you only need to implement the ScreenNameValidator interface

Cheers!